# How to configure apache to serve http://svn.example.com/robots.txt?

Tags: apache, svn, robots.txt, mod-dav-svn

I access SVN repositories via

- http://svn.example.com/repo1
- http://svn.example.com/repo2
- ...

with the following Apache configuration

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>
    ServerName svn.example.com

    <Location />
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /path/to/svn/repositories
        AuthzSVNAccessFile /path/to/svn/conf/auth_policy
        Satisfy Any

        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repository"
        AuthUserFile /path/to/svn/conf/passwdfile
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to prevent web crawlers from indexing the public repositories, but I cannot figure out how to properly set up the configuration to serve `robots.txt` from `http://svn.example.com/robots.txt`.

I have found a thread ["stopping webcrawlers using robots.txt"](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&dsMessageId=761161) from 2006, but it didn't help me solve the problem (Ryan's suggestion for redirection didn't work).

EDIT: I would prefer to keep the repositories at the top level rather than moving them to http://svn.example.com/something/*reponame*.

Comment: It is up to the bot to read (or not) the bots file... do not use it for security

Comment: Non-public repositories are password-protected, so it's not about security. Public repositories are ... well, public, but I don't want the results to appear in search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your Subversion repositories' virtual directory in the root of your server:

#### Wrong

```
<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /path/to/svn/repositories
```

#### Right

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /path/to/svn/repositories
```

Instead of your repository root being `http://svn.example.com`, it will be `http://svn.exmaple.com/svn`. This frees up `http://svn.example.com` to be a true document root which means you can add some documentation about your site, and put in a `robots.txt` file under `http://svn.example.com/robots.txt`.

Now, a well behaved robot will see the `robot.txt` file and not index your Subversion repository.

Comment: I'm aware that moving repositories one level down would solve the problem of `robots.txt`, but moving repositories to another URL is precisely something that I would like to avoid. I already have "svn" as a subdomain and introducing another "svn" seems superfluous, involves more typing + all the users would need to fix their checkouts. (In all honesty I would probably prefer spending time blacklisting IPs from different bots than moving repositories to a new location.)

Comment: You **might** be able to do both a document root and an SVN repo at the same virtual root directory. Try defining the DocumentRoot and ServerRoot directives in your http.conf file before you define your `<Location />` for your SVN repositories. See if you can create an `index.html` that will display at the URL root. I know this was possible in older versions of Apache httpd. It's worth giving it a shot. Just be careful that you could end up with collisions if someone defines an HTML directory the same as a Subversion repo.

Comment: @DavidW.: It needs to be called `robots.txt` (not `robot.txt`).